# Why do I get "type xxx is defined in an assembly that is not referenced"?

Tags: c#, mongodb, reference

I have the following C# project structure:

Main.dll
reference to -> Util.dll

```
class One {
    void function1() {
        Two.Function2("foo", "bar");
    }
}
```

Util.dll
reference to -> MongoDB.Driver.dll

```
class Two {
    public static void function2(string para1, string para2) {
        function2(null, para1, para2)
    }

    protected static void function2(IMongoQuery query, string para1, string para2) {
        // do a MongoDB query
    }
}
```

If I try to build Main.dll i get:

> The type 'MongoDB.Driver.IMongoQuery' is defined in an assembly that
>   is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'MongoDB.Driver, Version=1.8.3.9, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=f686731cfb9cc103'.

Adding the reference will resolve the problem, but I don't understand why the Main project needs to know about this parameter type? Am I doing something wrong? I don't know If this is something MongoDB related, I only want to hide MongoDB from above layers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a reference to MongoDB in your public (yes, protected is counted as public in this case because your other assembly can "see" it via derived classes) interface, so you need to include it.

Find a solution where you don't expose the types to classes outside your assembly. The `internal` keyword for example.

Comment: that explains it, but I can't use 'internal' cause I need to derive from this class in a third assembly. So I need to live with this...

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using a class that takes a parameter that isn't in an assembly referenced by `Main.dll`. The compiler won't attempt to resolve the dependencies of your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Two.function2` method is `protected` and uses an `IMongoQuery` parameter. This method is potentially visible to any class deriving from `Two` and as such the Main.dll needs a reference to the MongoDB assembly.